# git-svn not a git command?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

While attempting to get an old svn dump of a project under git control, I ran into an interesting problem.  Whenever I run `git svn`, I get an error saying it isn't a git command, yet there is documentation for it that I can pull up using `git help`.  Is there something wrong with my install, or am I just missing something here?

Edit:  I should probably also mention that I am running msysGit version 1.6.1.9.g97c34 under Windows XP, and the error I get is:

```
$ git svn 
git: 'svn' is not a
git-command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
        fsck
        show
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am not sure that [git svn has ever worked](http://osdir.com/ml/version-control.msysgit/2008-01/msg00225.html) with recent Git Windows distribution (post 1.5.6).

Many problems [have been reported](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/2433) before, so `git svn` may very much be not included in current msysGit releases.

Another current active "Git on Windows" development [mingw.git](http://repo.or.cz/w/git/mingw.git) does state in its [README](http://repo.or.cz/w/git/mingw.git?a=blob_plain;f=README.MinGW;hb=master) that svn does not work.

This [thread of Msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=174#c8) does suggest that git svn may be reintegrated at some points, but progress are still slow.

---

Update: from MSysGit1.6.2 (early March 2009), **`git-svn` works again**. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623518/msysgit-on-windows-what-should-i-be-aware-of-if-any/647601#647601).

---

Update: with a [modern (2017) Git for Windows 2.x](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), `git svn` is already included.
No need for `sudo apt-get install git-svn`, which would only be possible in a [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) shell session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) anyway.

Comment: git svn is certainly bundled with Git now on Windows :)

Comment: @TodThomson I agree, and that is what my update from March 2009 is saying.

Comment: for windows 10 users `sudo apt-get install git-svn`

Answer (score 293):

I just check on my newly installed ubuntu box and it wasn't installed even with git-core installed. A simple:

```
sudo apt-get install git-svn
```

or your distro equivalent should fix it.

Answer (score 34):

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-svn
```

Comment: The ppa is optional. git-svn is included in the standard repository.

Comment: Old question but still when git-svn is installed on Ubuntu, I think it should be added that we have to use *git svn* and not *git-svn*

Comment: I needed the ppa part on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: `apt-get update` needs `sudo` also. I've tried to update the response but since the edit is less than 6 characters SO doesn't allow me to do it

Answer (score 8):

It wasn't installed on my fresh install of Ubuntu on WSL -

```
sudo apt install git-svn
```

sorted it:

```
❯ git svn
git-svn - bidirectional operations between a single Subversion tree and git
...
```

Comment: I tried this solution and works. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Under my system I've had this trouble:

```
$ git svn
Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0
/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/i486-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/i486-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/i486-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 29.
```

because I don't have Subversion Perl bindings installed. Try installing them and running the command again.

Comment: I've also seen this with the Perl bindings installed in a different location than Git expected;  corrected with a symlink.

Answer (score 7):

For posterity: On CentOS 7, just run `sudo yum install git-svn`.

Answer (score 5):

MacPorts version:

```
port install git +svn
```

(Note: you likely need to `port deactivate git` first)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error under Cygwin 1.7. It was solved by installing the git-svn package with Cygwin setup.

Answer (score 3):

On Gentoo , you should build git with USE="subversion"

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS I used

```
sudo yum install git-svn
```

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem on RHEL6, i.e.,

> Can't locate Git/SVN.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 25.

My solution:

```
sudo yum install subversion-perl
chmod 755  /usr/local/share/perl5/ (and sub dirs, as they were only readable by root)
```

Comment: This was exactly my issue. The `/usr/local/share/perl5` directory and contents needed those permissions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If git-svn is not part of mSysGit, I recommend using a small UNIX server to host your gateway repository that clones your svn repository, and then clone that repository onto your Windows machine.  This is the approach I am using for interacting with CVS from git.

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora I had to install it with

```
sudo dnf install -y git-svn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Homebrew (or/are on MacOS) this is the command I used

`brew install git-svn`

[link to docs](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/git-svn)